# Which service is responsible for GPO?

Tags: group-policy, domain, service, windows-service, infrastructure

Can someone please tell me what service should I start to apply GPO on my DC.
I have a GPO on my DC but it does not apply on it.
(I was asked specifically about services so it must be the problem.)
Thank you.

Comment: שלום שירה
There's a group policy service but Zoran's answer below is almost certainly correct.  Group policy doesn't apply instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Run `gppdate` in CMD with force parameter.

Open Command Prompt and type `gpupdate /force` and hit enter.

[image]

After group policy update restart the server.